# Correlation test over time

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, econometrics

For my research I want to test whether the influence that certain variables have on compensation, have changed over time.  The **influence** of this variables are measured by looking at the correlation.  But I do not know how to test whether the correlation between these variables and my dependent  (Compensation) has changed significantly between the two time periods.

As an example, I have multiple variables such as performance, firm size and board independence and some dummy variables (yes/no).  **I want to look if the influence that performance, firm size etc has on the compensation of a CEO has changed between two years,** such as 2008 and 2012. **This means I have two datasets with the same independent and dependent (compensation) variables, testing whether influence on compensation has changed over time?** **How should I do this using a correlation test or should I do a completely different kind of test?**

Comment: How many variables do you have? Correlations are between two variables at a time.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Note that your username, identicon, & a link to your user page 
are automatically added to every post you make, so there is no need to sign 
your posts. In fact, we prefer you don't.  (There's also no need to tag with "SPSS", since your question is really about statistical concepts and isn't software-specific.)

Comment: You might want to edit your question to clarify what you're really looking for here. If your underlying issue is seeing whether the influence of your independent variables has changed over time, then it isn't clear that a test for change in correlation is necessarily the best way of going about it.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, I have multiple variables such as performance, firm size and board independence. For example i want to look if the influence that performance has on the compensation of a CEO has changed between two years, such as 2008 and 2012. Or should I do a completely different kind of test?